# SQL Statement sorting nvarchar

Tags: sql

```
STD-00-1

STD-00-2

STD-00-10

STD-00-1(T)

STD-00-2(T)

STD-00-10(T)

STD-05-1

STD-05-2

STD-05-10

STD-05-1(T)

STD-05-2(T)

STD-05-10(T)

WIP-00-1

WIP-00-1(T)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY [COLUMN]
```

Next time, please be a little more specific.

Comment: This will put `STD-00-10` before `STD-00-2`

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to parse the parts and sort.  The example query creates fields `v1, v2, ...` with the data you can sort on.  `v1` contains `STD`, `v2` contains the first number, `v3` is 1 if `(T)` is present, and `v4` is the second number.  The outer query then uses those fields to sort, like:

```
select  YourColumn
from    (
    select  substring(YourColumn,1,3) as v1
    ,       cast(substring(YourColumn,5,2) as int) as v2
    ,       case when YourColumn like '%(T)%' then 1 else 0 end as v3
    ,       cast(replace(substring(YourColumn,8,len(YourColumn)-7),'(T)','') 
                 as int) as v4
    ,       YourColumn
    from    YourTable
) sub
order by v1, v2, v3, v4
```

For your example data, this returns:

```
v1  v2  v3  v4  YourColumn     
STD 0   0   1   STD-00-1       
STD 0   0   2   STD-00-2       
STD 0   0   10  STD-00-10      
STD 0   1   1   STD-00-1(T)    
STD 0   1   2   STD-00-2(T)    
STD 0   1   10  STD-00-10(T)   
STD 5   0   1   STD-05-1       
STD 5   0   2   STD-05-2       
STD 5   0   10  STD-05-10      
STD 5   1   1   STD-05-1(T)    
STD 5   1   2   STD-05-2(T)    
STD 5   1   10  STD-05-10(T)   
WIP 0   0   1   WIP-00-1       
WIP 0   1   1   WIP-00-1(T)
```

Additional tweaks might be required.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is that You should achive in your sql query only.

```
select name from table_name ORDER By name
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Andomar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848512/sql-statement-sorting-nvarchar/2848991#2848991) if you can't change the schema.

If however you *can* change the schema, I would suggest the *best* thing to do would be:

- separate out the different parts into separate columns, typed appropriately to the data they actually hold
- for maintaining existing functionality, have a new *computed* column that is their concatenation, with the `-` separators and casting as appropriate
- `ORDER BY` the columns separately when you want to sort